# Error en la condición php

Tags: php

Tengo el sgte. Problema realmente es posible tener una condicion dentro de una variable en php, alguna posible solucion

`[25-Feb-2017 22:02:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\zona\clases\productos.class.php on line 61`

```
public function buscar_index($texto_buscar) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos " . "where upper(titulo_producto) like '%" . strtoupper($texto_buscar) . "%' ";
    $rs = $this->consulta($sql);
    $registros = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $imagen = "<img src='../img/" . $row["imagen_producto"] . "' class='img-lista' alt='" . $row["imagen_producto"] . "'>";

        $registros .= '<div class="product-item previews-3 large '.$row['categoria'].'">';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-inside">';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-info">';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-photo">';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-gallery-main">';
        $registros .= '<a href="#">';
        $registros .= '<img class="product-image-photo" src="img/'.$row['imagen_producto'].'" alt="">';
        $registros .= '</a>';
        $registros .= '<a href="quick-view.php?id='.$row['id_producto'].'" title="Quick View" class="quick-view-link quick-view-btn">';
        $registros .= '<i class="icon icon-eye"></i>'; 
        $registros .= '<span>Vista rapida</span>';
        $registros .= '</a>';
        $registros .= '</div>';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-actions">';
        $registros .= '<div class="share-button toBottom">';
        $registros .= '<span class="toggle"></span>';
        $registros .= '<ul class="social-list">';
        $registros .= '<li>';
        $registros .= '<a href="#" class="icon icon-twitter-logo twitter"></a>';
        $registros .= '</li>';
        $registros .= '<li>';
        $registros .= '<a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook-logo facebook"></a>';
        $registros .= '</li>';
        $registros .= '</ul>';
        $registros .= '</div>';
        $registros .= '</div>'; 
        $registros .= '</div>';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-details">';
        $registros .= '<div class="product-item-name">';
        $registros .= '<a href="quick-view.php?id='.$row['id_producto'].'" title="Quick View" class="quick-view-link ">'.$row['titulo_producto'].'</a>';
        $registros .= '</div>';
        $registros .=    '<div class="product-item-description">Neque porro quisquam est, q incidunt ut labore</div>';
        $registros .=    '<div class="price-box">';
        $registros .=    '<span class="price-container">';
        $registros .=    '<span class="price-wrapper">';
        $registros .=    '<span class="price">Gs. '.$row['precio_producto'].'</span>';
        $registros .=    '</span>';
        $registros .=    '</span>';
        $registros .=    '</div>';
        $registros .=    '<div class="product-size watches">';
        $registros .=    '<ul class="size-list">'; 
        $registros .=   ''if($row["tallaxp"]>0)'<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">X</span></a></li>';


        $registros .=    '</ul>';
        $registros .=    '</div>';
        $registros .=    '<button class="btn add-to-cart" data-product="'.$row['id_producto'].'" onclick="agregar_carrito($(this))"  >';
        $registros .=    '<i class="icon icon-cart"></i>';
        $registros .=    '<span>Agregar a carrito</span>';
        $registros .=    '</button>';
        $registros .=    '</div>';
        $registros .=    '</div>';
        $registros .=    '</div>';


    }
    if ($registros == "") {
        $registros = '<tr>';
        $registros .= '<td colspan="5">';
        $registros .= 'No existen registros ...';
        $registros .= '</td>';
        $registros .= '</tr>';
    }

    $arr = array('registros' => $registros);
    return ($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieres interpolar texto condicionalmente, en vez de poner

```
$registros .=   ''if($row["tallaxp"]>0)'<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">X</span></a></li>';
```

Debes usar

```
$registros .=  ($row["tallaxp"]>0)? '<li><a href="#" ><span class="value">X</span></a></li>': '' ;
```

Esto se conoce como [Operador Ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).